# Может ли вся станица HTML, включая хедер, обновиться без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: html

Может ли вся станица HTML, включая хедер, обновиться без перезагрузки страницы?

Знаю, что аяксом можно сделать запрос к серверу, поменять какой-то тег или часть страницы. Знаю, что можно просто джава скриптом поменять через InnerHTML.

А возможно что-то типа такого Window.InnerHTML или document.InnerHTML? Только помните, что header /header тоже должен изменяться.

Comment: @javascript, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = '<meta content="Вася Пупкин" name="author"><style>h1{font-weight:normal;}</style>';
```